# How to compare elements to each other of two string arrays and print only elements with no match? C (not C++)

Tags: c, compare

I have got two arrays like this: `char * list_of_names[size]` and `char* list_of_names_2[size]`
But these two arrays could contain different number of names. For example: List1: "aa","bbb","ccc","ddd","QQQ" and List2: "aa","ccc","ddd" ...And I need print something like that: "no match for "bbb" and "QQQ"
I can print elements with match but I can't print elements which no match

I've got this so far:

```
for(i=0;i<size_of_1st_list;i++)
{
    for(l=0;l<size_of_2nd_list;l++)
    {
           if(strcmp(list_of_names[i],list_of_names_2[l])==0){
               printf("%s - match - %s\n", list_of_names[i]); //prints matches.. and I need print elements which the 2nd array doesn't contain....
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to print data of list1 which do not present in list2?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I don't think your "strcmp" line would respond correctly, because strcmp returns 0 if the strings match, and code within if() statement would not execute. Therefore, I suggest correcting this with adding an '!' operator ( logic negation ), so if strcmp will return 0 ( strings match ) !(strcmp(...)) will return 1 and if statement will print a match. And about non-matching elements, you can add an 'else' clause to the statement, therefore if !(strcmp(...)) is something else than 0, it will mean a mismatch of strings, and you can print them with your preferred message.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write "==0" into if()

Comment: Ok I understand. I still believe you can catch a solution with the rest of my answer and a bit of modification.

Comment: I'm not sure If I understand you.. do you mean something like this? else{if(strcmp(...)!=0)}

Comment: Not exactly, rather something like:
if !(strcmp(....)
{do this} // in case upper statement is true ( new line )
else {do that} // in any other case

Comment: Well, the basic if-else statement actually :
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/if-else-statement-in-c-program/

Answer (score 0):

@James C is right about `strcmp` issue. You can both add `!` operator at the beginning or check if it is equal to 0. About non-matching elements, instead of an else statement, you can add a flag to control if there is no match. Because that kind of an else statement will show non-match even if there is a match of strings with different indices. You need to check whole array to find if there is no match.

Also, on your printf statement, you want two string arguments but you pass only one. So if it is also fixed, code like below should do your work:

```
int flag;
for(i=0;i<size_of_1st_list;i++)
    {
    flag = 0;
    for(l=0;l<size_of_2nd_list;l++)
        {
        if(strcmp(list_of_names[i],list_of_names_2[l]) == 0)
            {
            flag = 1;
            printf("%s - match - %s\n", list_of_names[i], list_of_name_2[l]);
            }
        }
    if(flag == 0)
        printf("No match for %s\n", list_of_names[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it works... I'm idiot...I tried that but I didn't give the second if after second for(){} :D ... Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

use the "break"

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(){
    char list_of_names[][16] = {"aa","bbb","ccc","ddd","QQQ"};
    char list_of_names_2[][16] = {"aa","ccc","ddd"};
    int size_of_1st_list = sizeof(list_of_names)/sizeof(list_of_names[0]);
    int size_of_2nd_list = sizeof(list_of_names_2)/sizeof(list_of_names_2[0]);
    int i, l;

    for(i=0; i<size_of_1st_list; i++)
    {
        int flag = 0;
        for(l=0; l<size_of_2nd_list; l++)
        {
            if(strcmp(list_of_names[i], list_of_names_2[l])==0)
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            printf("No match for %s\n", list_of_names[i]);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```